# List all paths in subversion repository with a certain property & value

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svnlook

Part of a repository is going to move to it's own repository on a new server, and this may break externals that have been set up.

How can I find a list of all paths that have externals set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an executable script 'find_externals.sh'

```
#!/bin/bash
repository='/path/to/repo'

echo find paths that have externals set
while read fullpath; do
        result=`svnlook proplist "$repository" "${fullpath}" -v`

        if [[ "$result" == *svn:ext* ]] ; then
                echo;echo "Path: '$fullpath'"
                echo $result
        fi
done
```

Call it like this

```
svnlook tree /path/to/repo --full-paths | ./find_externals.sh
```