# Fast method to find Subversion externals using SVNLOOK

Tags: svn, scripting, svnlook

I have a large repo, over 100GB, that I want to search for external property values.

I've used a method similar to the one discussed here:

[List all paths in subversion repository with a certain property & value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644276/list-all-paths-in-subversion-repository-with-a-certain-property-value)

The problem is that it is very slow to traverse the whole repo and get the values.

Does svn store properties per path in a cache somewhere is or there a faster way of searching a repository?

I'm not looking for a product like Fisheye just something I can script.

Comment: if you have a checkout you can do an `svn stat` which would be a bit more complicated to parse then svnlooking each node but is doable. Not sure if that would be faster though.

Comment: I considered that but instead of svn stat I could just search the sqlite database. I'd rather not have a checkout as I want to apply this to other repos that are larger than the one I'm currently working with.